# R: Where a value in two data frames is the same, apply a set of condition on one to determine its classification

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have two sets of data.  I wish to apply a classification (low, mid.lo, mid.up, high) one the first set (income by year) based on conditions contained in the other (year, and three breakpoints).  Below are samples from those data sets - the real sets are much larger and are not of the same length.

income

```
    Country Year    GNI.caput
Argentina   2000    7470
Argentina   2001    7000
Argentina   2002    4050
Argentina   2003    3670
Argentina   2004    3810
Denmark 2000    32660
Denmark 2001    31440
Denmark 2002    30870
Denmark 2003    34850
Denmark 2004    42760
Kenya   2000    420
Kenya   2001    400
Kenya   2002    390
Kenya   2003    410
Kenya   2004    460
Philippines 2000    1230
Philippines 2001    1230
Philippines 2002    1190
Philippines 2003    1270
Philippines 2004    1400
```

breaks

```
Year    Break.1 Break.2 Break.3
2004    825 3225    10065
2003    765 3035    9385
2002    735 2935    9075
2001    745 2975    9205
2000    755 2995    9265
```

I have tried the following sets of loops, but neither completes, generating several errors each.

Attempt 1

```
for(i in seq_along(gni.data)){
    while(gni.data$Year == break.pts$Year) {
        if(gni.data$GNI.caput <= break.pts$Break.1) {
            gni.data$Indicator <- "Low"
        } else if(gni.data$GNI.caput <= break.pts$Break.2) {
            gni.data$Indicator <- "Mid.Low"
        } else if(gni.data$GNI.caput <= break.pts$Break.3) {
            gni.data$Indicator <- "Mid.Up"
        } else if(gni.data$GNI.caput > break.pts$Break.3) {
            gni.data$Indicator <- "High"
        } else gni.data$Indicator <- "NA"
    }
}
```

Warning messages:
1: In gni.data$Year == break.pts$Year :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In while (gni.data$Year == break.pts$Year) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
...

Attempt 2

```
for(i in seq_along(gni.data)){
    while(gni.data$Year == break.pts$Year) {
        ifelse(gni.data$GNI.caput <= break.pts$Break.1, gni.data$Indicator <- "Low", 
                ifelse(gni.data$GNI.caput <= break.pts$Break.2, gni.data$Indicator <- "Mid.Lo",
                       ifelse(gni.data$GNI.caput <= break.pts$Break.3, gni.data$Indicator <- "Mid.Up",
                              ifelse(gni.data$GNI.caput > break.pts$Break.3, gni.data$Indicator <- "High",
                                     gni.data$Indicator <- "NA"))))
    }
}
```

Warning messages same as for attempt 1.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your warning message implies that you have more than one element in break.pts$Year. If that is on purpose, then you can try replacing your "==" with "%in%", which will accept a vector.

Comment: This would probably be easier to do if you merge the two data sets, using the country-year one as `x`, the one with the cuts as `y`, and setting `all.x=TRUE`. Then you could write simpler code without for loops using a nested pair of calls to `ifelse()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by temporarily merging the two data frames in a call to `with()` and then using nested `ifelse()` calls to make the new variable, like this:

```
# Toy data to test
df <- data.frame(country=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=3), year=rep(seq(2000,2002), 3), gdp = rnorm(9, 5000, 1000), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
cuts <- data.frame(year = seq(2000,2002), break.1=c(4000,4500,4000), break.2=c(5000,5500,5000), break.3=c(6000,6500,6000))

# Create new variable using merge of two data sets
df$class <- with(merge(df, cuts, all.x=TRUE),
    ifelse(gdp < break.1, "lo", ifelse(gdp >= break.1 & gdp < break.2, "mid.lo",
        ifelse(gdp >= break.2 & gdp < break.3, "mid.hi", ifelse(gdp >= break.3, "hi", NA)))))

# Result
> newdf
  year country      gdp break.1 break.2 break.3  class
1 2000       A 5510.243    4000    5000    6000 mid.hi
2 2000       C 6404.494    4000    5000    6000     hi
3 2000       B 6125.383    4000    5000    6000     hi
4 2001       A 4899.577    4500    5500    6500 mid.lo
5 2001       B 4678.249    4500    5500    6500 mid.lo
6 2001       C 6026.577    4500    5500    6500 mid.hi
7 2002       B 6350.749    4000    5000    6000     hi
8 2002       A 7225.358    4000    5000    6000     hi
9 2002       C 5469.354    4000    5000    6000 mid.hi
```

You could also use `dplyr` and its piping operator to merge, recode, sort, and cut the superfluous columns all in one go:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(df, cuts) %>%
    mutate(class = ifelse(gdp < break.1, "lo", ifelse(gdp >= break.1 & gdp < break.2, "mid.lo",
    ifelse(gdp >= break.2 & gdp < break.3, "mid.hi", ifelse(gdp >= break.3, "hi", NA))))) %>%
    arrange(country, year) %>%
    select(-break.1, -break.2, -break.3)

# Result
>df
  country year      gdp  class
1       A 2000 5510.243 mid.hi
2       A 2001 4899.577 mid.lo
3       A 2002 7225.358     hi
4       B 2000 6125.383     hi
5       B 2001 4678.249 mid.lo
6       B 2002 6350.749     hi
7       C 2000 6404.494     hi
8       C 2001 6026.577 mid.hi
9       C 2002 5469.354 mid.hi
```

Comment: Thanks! Much more elegant than my muddled, overcomplicated attempt.

Comment: Glad it worked. I revised the base R version to embed the merge in the line that creates the new variable so you can do it in one shot without creating new objects.