# how to compare the values of two data frames in r and create a new data frame as a result in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

my.data.1

```
       AIRLINE    STORES
[1]    500        100
[2]    300        200
```

my.data.2

```
       AIRLINE   STORES
33%    50        25
67%    150       65
```

I want to create an new data frame by comparing them by taking each value from columns of my.data.1 and check if it is larger than or lesser than or in between the values of the corresponding column in my.data.2

For example:

```
  my.data.1[1, 'AIRLINE'] < my.data.2['33%', 'AIRLINE'] = 'LOW'

  my.data.1[1, 'AIRLINE'] > my.data.2['67%', 'AIRLINE'] = 'HIGH'

  my.data.1[1, 'AIRLINE'] >= my.data.2['33%', 'AIRLINE'] && 
      my.data.1[1, 'AIRLINE'] <= my.data.2['67%', 'AIRLINE'] = 'MED'
```

so that I will have a resulting data fame that will look like

```
       AIRLINE    STORES
[1]    HIGH        HIGH
[2]    HIGH        HIGH
```

Comment: No clarity in your question what do you want to compare. Checking Airline column again same airline column, not sure what you are trying to achieve. Check this link, it might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406412/r-where-a-value-in-two-data-frames-is-the-same-apply-a-set-of-condition-on-one

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Try if the below works for you:

```
df1 <- data.frame(AIRLINE = c(500, 300),
                  STORES = c(100, 200))
df2 <- data.frame(AIRLINE = c(50, 150),
                  STORES = c(25, 65))
getScore <- function(x, y) {
  ifelse(x < y[1], "LOW",
         ifelse(x > y[2], "HIGH", "MED"))
}
df3 <- df1
df3$AIRLINE <- sapply(df1$AIRLINE, getScore, df2$AIRLINE)
df3$STORES <- sapply(df1$STORES, getScore, df2$STORES)         
df3
  AIRLINE STORES
1    HIGH   HIGH
2    HIGH   HIGH
```

Comment: how about the 'MED', how to calculate that

Comment: the MED means if the value in first data frame is in between the 33% and 67% values in second data frame